# find lighter and darker colors based on any color from white to black

Tags: c#, windows-8, colors, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

Can any one tell me how can I do same as  [0to255](http://0to255.com/) in a Windows Store app (C#)?

In short I need a logic in which I will pass a color & it will give me a list of color.

```
private List<string> GetColorCollection(string hexcolor)
{
    //TODO: 
}
```

`GetColorCollection(510099)` should give me the result same as [this](http://0to255.com/510099).

Answer (score 1):

The website you linked to uses HSL (Hue Saturation Lightness) instead of RGB to represent the colors, and then varies the Lightness from 0 to 255 (hence the name).

The `Color` class provides `getBrightness()`, but nothing to manipulate the Lightness directly. Luckily, you're not the first person to need that conversion - you can just use the `ColorRGB` class from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942/hsl-in-net).

Comment: You ought to mention gamma correction, lightness is not linear.

Comment: ColorRGB class is not applicable to me. I am creating app for Windows 8 & Windows phone. `System.Drawing.Color` has GetHue() & other methods  & it's applicable to WinForms.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that. However, it's not hard to find a [fully usable implementation of an RGB-HSL converter](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/HSL-Colors-in-Silverlight.aspx). Once you have that, Just plug it in the appropriate places in the ```ColorRGB``` class

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this one, and I can't get the right values (same as the website) but, I think this is pretty close. *I hope this is useful to you.*

I tested it with the value: 15bee1

http://0to255.com/15bee1

And these are my results:

[image: Gradient of 0to255]

I don't like to create functions that has strings as input instead when colors meant. So I made some conversion.

And this is the code:

```
// convert the Color type to String notation
private string ColorToString(Color color)
{
    return String.Format("{0:x2}{1:x2}{2:x2}", color.R, color.G, color.B);
}

// convert the string notation to color type
private Color StringToColor(string hexcolor)
{
    byte r = Convert.ToByte(hexcolor.Substring(0, 2), 16);
    byte g = Convert.ToByte(hexcolor.Substring(2, 2), 16);
    byte b = Convert.ToByte(hexcolor.Substring(4, 2), 16);

    return new Color { R = r, G = g, B = b };
}

// This function calculates a gradient from <color1> to <color2> in <steps> steps
private IEnumerable<Color> GetColorGradient(Color color1, Color color2, int steps)
{
    int rD = color2.R - color1.R;
    int gD = color2.G - color1.G;
    int bD = color2.B - color1.B;

    for (int i = 1; i < steps; i++)
        yield return new Color
        {
            R = (byte)(color1.R + (rD * i / (steps))),
            G = (byte)(color1.G + (gD * i / (steps))),
            B = (byte)(color1.B + (bD * i / (steps))),
        };
}

// This will append two gradients (white->color->black)
private IEnumerable<Color> GetColorCollection(Color color, int steps)
{
    int grayValue = (color.R + color.G + color.B) / 3;

    // with the gray value I will determine the lightness of the color, so what step it should start. I don't want 16 white values, when I input a light color.
    int currentStep = (grayValue * steps / 256) - 1;

    yield return Colors.White;

    foreach (Color c in GetColorGradient(Colors.White, color, currentStep))
        yield return c;

    yield return color;

    foreach (Color c in GetColorGradient(color, Colors.Black, steps - currentStep - 1))
        yield return c;

    yield return Colors.Black;
}

// this function will convert a IEnumerable<Color> to IEnumerable<string>
private IEnumerable<string> GetColorCollection(string hexcolor, int steps)
{
    foreach (Color newColor in GetColorCollection(StringToColor(hexcolor), steps))
        yield return ColorToString(newColor);
}
```

And this is how to call it:

```
string hexcolor = "15bee1";

IEnumerable<string> results = GetColorCollection(hexcolor, 32);
```

Comment: It doesn't work correctly when darker color is passed as argument. Try [150028](http://0to255.com/150028), [430500](http://0to255.com/430500) ,[fe9a82](http://0to255.com/fe9a82) & [322423](http://0to255.com/322423)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test this, but should work.

First, get a [System.Drawing.Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) from hexcode using [ColorTranslator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.aspx)

```
 System.Drawing.Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF00FF");
```

Then, use [ControlPaint.Light](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wz9t9fy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [ControlPaint.Dark](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h3fxkc2x.aspx) to adjust the brightness of the color

```
List<Color> lighterColors = new List<Color>();
List<Color> darkerColors = new List<Color>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   lighterColors.Add(ControlPaint.Light(color, (float)(i / 10));
   darkerColors.Add(ControlPaint.Dark(color, (float)(i / 10));
}
```

Finally, convert each color in the list back to hex

```
string hexcode = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(color);
```

Comment: This is not useful to me. I am creating windows 8 and windows phone 8 app. Also the result should be same or near to 0to255.com